# Spring hibernate OpenSessionInViewFilter

Tags: spring, hibernate, double, sessionfactory

i need help, i use custom opensessioninviewfilter by exend it, i override the doFilterInternal method, i store sessionFactory in static  ThredLocal variable :

```
public static ThreadLocal<SessionFactory> current = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

in my dao i check weither the sessionFactory is same used in my Filter, i realize that are not same sessionFactory, there are two different instance,

DAO :

```
@Autowired
 protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

opensessionViewFilter.doFilterInternal 
MyClass.current.set(session);

My serrive Layer :

```
@Service("comiteService")
@Transactional
public class CommiteServiceImpl implements CommiteService{
    @Autowired
    CommiteDao dao;
```

Web.xml :

```
<filter>
     <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.web.filter.MyOpenViewInSession</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
         <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
     <init-param>
      <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>

      </init-param>
     </filter>
```

applicationContext.xml :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.entity"/>


        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql:true}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql:true}</prop>


                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" >false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" >org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                    <prop key="org.hibernate logging">ALL</prop>
                <prop key="net.sf.Ehcache.configurationResourceName">/Ehcache.xml</prop>
               <!--  <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans"> true</prop> -->
                <prop key="spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics" >true</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            </props>
        </property>       
    </bean>
```

in my DAO i do the following to check if sessionFactory is same as in filter or different :

```
if(System.identityHashCode(getSessionFactory()) == System.identityHashCode(MyClass.current))
            System.out.println("sessionfactory is same");
            else System.out.println("SessionFactory are not same");
```

the output was : "SessionFactory are not same"

Comment: Why store the sessionfactory? You should be storing the session not the sessionfactory,

Comment: i store the sessionfactory in  opensessionvienfilter in order to check if it is same as in my DAO class, i found that are not same, which is not normal because sessionfactory is singleton

Comment: Still I don’t see the case why you would do that. Nonetheless if they aren’t the same you are loading your configuration multiple times.

Comment: look in my opensessioninviefilter i do this :  SessionHolder sessionHolder = new SessionHolder(session);
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, sessionHolder);

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you very much, yes i check and i found that i load config twice